# Trouble with nginx and PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, iptables, php-fpm

I am having trouble getting my webserver (nginx) to work with php-fpm. The page keeps loading and then the loading time expires.

I hope one of you can help me resolve this issue. I have made an export of my active iptables rules in hopes of getting a clue as to what is wrong.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 9962 1071K fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
 9982 1106K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  439 25076 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
  117  5964 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:http
   24  1372 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ftp
   15   620 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpts:20000:30000
   88  4280 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:https
   54  2438 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 100/sec burst 100
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 1/sec burst 10
 2110  110K syn-flood  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
 2687  163K REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 85 packets, 14451 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 7951  908K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain syn-flood (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2110  110K RETURN     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/sec burst 6
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

#### Update

Thanks for the reply. It doesn't seem to be in my iptables.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <my domain>.<my tld>;
    access_log /data/wwwlogs/<mydomain>.<mytld>_nginx.log combined;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/conf/rewrite/none.conf;
    root /data/wwwroot/<mydomain>.<mytld>;


    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        #fastcgi_pass remote_php_ip:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-cgi.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|flv|ico)$ {
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
        }
    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$ {
        expires 7d;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

I need to note that I am absolutely unexperienced with iptables and a mere beginner in using linux.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your issue comes from the firewall.

Comment: It was the only thing I could think of. I'll check the nginx logs again.

Comment: What does the nginx error log show? Most often it is located under `/var/log/nginx`.

Answer (score 2):

Without testing this myself, I can't be sure, but it seems like this is just a case of a bad regex line for directing requests to your php-fpm engine.

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
```

Will only match location requests which end with ".php/" (which is uncommon), or explicitly end with ".php". I'm assuming you used the guide [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/), which is fine (though I've never seen anyone do it this way before), but if you don't include the `if` statement as shown there, it may lead to broken requests. There's also the problem that can bite you, that if you don't set something like

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /your/php/path/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

explicitly (for instance, implicitly with $document_root in `fastcgi.conf`), you might be pointing at the wrong path.

The other two things to keep in mind is that you have no `location /` block to deal with all other requests which aren't explicitly found as-is in your root directory, and finally you've listed your php block at the top, which is incorrect— it will attempt to match for URI's ending in php first, rather than matching and serving the static files first (jpg, ico, etc.) which is typically what you want.